# Is there a tutorial to develop its own app on Huawei band 6?

Tags: iot, sensors, remote-server, huawei-mobile-services, wearables

I own a Huawei band 6 and want to develop my own app to remote control the band and its sensors and then get data. Then I want to be able to send this data to a server through internet : to be able to access the health data (heart beat and Oximetry) of a remote patient.

If it seems more complicated, would it be easier to use Wear Os (Google) with another brand of the wearable ?

Comment: Huawei Band 6 does not support the installation of apps. If you need to, you could develop apps on your phone and integrate Huawei Health Kit to read data generated by your band or watch. kindly check [this docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/health-introduce-0000001053684429?ha_source=hms1).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This solution seems to meet my need. 
But as Huawei Band 6 runs Lite OS, is it easier to develop under a Wear OS band (e.g. HUAWEI WATCH GT 3 ) ?
I had checked the development guides before my initial post, but I'm struggling getting started with a "hello world" app that would allow to read heart rate at an every given time laps.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to put an app directly onto the Huawei Band 6, it is currently not open to developers.

You can find a list of devices that are currently open to developers here. https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/connectivity-Guides/service-introduction-0000000000018585

Alternatively, I recommend integrating the Huawei Health kit into a phone app based on the use case you described. Health kit allows phone apps to access the health & fitness data collected by Huawei wearables.

To answer B.M's question:

That is correct, you do not have to change the watch for the phone app option. These are two distinctly different options that I have described. Developing a watch app is different from creating a phone app that integrates the Huawei Health Kit. Each one serves a different purpose, and based on your use case, I believe that the a phone app makes the most sense.

Watch App: Can be only be developed on specific Huawei Watch models.

Phone App: Works with all Huawei wearables when Huawei Health Kit is integrated.

Please note that Wear OS (Google) is not used on Huawei wearables and does not work with the Huawei Health Kit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
Are you sure? even using Huawei Health kit, I have to use a Wear OS band to be able to access health data ? The comment of shirley on my question doesn't mention I have to change the band.

Comment: @b.m more info. added to my answer.

Comment: Thanks and Sorry, I wanted to talk about Harmony Os (Not Wear Os, the competitor). So to summarize, I can use a band 6 (Lite Os) and and a smartphone (with Huawei Health app) to be able to react with the watch (activate sensors and read specific data) or even develop my own app.
My second question, is there tutorial/books to do so ?

Comment: As I haven't started the development yet, would it be easier to choose the Wear Os solution and rather buy a Samsung Watch ?